# social:notConnected tag in Thymeleaf with Spring Social

Tags: html, spring, jsp, thymeleaf, spring-social

I am changing my JSP views to HTML Thymeleaf views and ran into a problem.

In my old JSP views I use a social:notConnected tag. However this seems to have been removed and the only one I can find are social:connected as showed here.

```
<div id="content" social:connected="facebook">
    This will only be rendered when connected to Facebook.
</div>
```

I want the notConnected tag to show my connect button when not connected, and hide it otherwise.

I could have done this with assigning a global variable but Thymeleaf does not seem to have support for this.

Any ideas for a nice solution to this? Only way I can think of is to embed javascript in the social:connected div to know if I should remove the other div.

PS: I added the Spring social dialect as this on my Thymeleaf Spring Template engine and everything works beside notConnected which probably are not implemented:

```
engine.addDialect(new SpringSocialDialect());
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For now I use the following:

```
    Connection<Twitter> twitter = connectionRepository.findPrimaryConnection(Twitter.class);
    model.addAttribute("connectedToTwitter", (twitter == null) ? false : true);
```

And in the view:

```
    <div th:if="!${connectedToTwitter}">
        Connect to Twitter buttons
    </div>
```

Will do something nicer when I find a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite old already. Yet I came upon the same issue today. I found that not-connected is first implemented in **spring-social-web:1.1.5.RELEASE**. I had to manually pin spring-social artifacts to this version as the current spring-social-google referes to 1.1.4.RELEASE which still lacks the feature.